# What does it mean the following "Rat Poison Squared"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

Warrent Buffett comapred Bitcoin as a "Rat Poison Squared"
I am wondering why he used the word squared and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

I’m guessing “squared” is used here to amplify the insult. Like “idiot squared” means not just an idiot, but a massive idiot from all four sides... complete idiot.

Comment: is this used only in negative meaning, can I say "my colleague is very clever squared"

Comment: It is mainly used in negative responses.

Comment: If you add squared to a noun, it of course makes an existing situation or thing worse. Rat poison on its own is bad.

Comment: @Stan I agree with your answer, but what evidence have you to support your comment that "It is mainly used in negative responses."? I don't sense "squared" to be inherently pejorative.

Answer (score 0):

I've always understood **squared** in that usage to mean "to the power of 2":

stupidity squared = stupidity<sup>[2](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=baka%5E2)</sup>

That is, very very stupid.